# Can I send email from Office 365 from a different email address?

Tags: email, office-365

Say I use Office 365 to pick up my email, all email I send is from my Office 365 address. I have a web app that sends email on my behalf from `admin@somedomain.com`, which is set up as a forwarder to my Office 365 address. This is so that people can reply to those emails and I will get the replies.

Is there any way, using Office 365, that I can set the `admin@somedomain.com` address as my from address?